# url.content in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

url.content in MVC

What can I use same like that for ASP.NET web forms?

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking for a method that accepts a relative path and generates a URL for ASP.NET web forms, see `Page.ResolveUrl` or `Page.ResolveClientUrl`.  ResolveUrl returns a path relative to the site root, whereas ResolveClientUrl returns a path relative to the current page.

Answer (score 1):

Use runat="server" like:

```
<a href="~/<your path>" runat="server">url.content sample</a>
```